# CSS not overiding Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Below is a bootstrap that I found and implemented in my coding. Im trying to generate the hover effect from white to green. However it is not letting me do so. 
My sass file is not overriding the bootstrap. Can someone help? Thanks.

```
 <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
           <li  id="activeRow"class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Users</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Suppliers</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Online Course</a></li>
       </ul>
 </div>



 #activeRow
      background-color:green
```

Comment: check the order in which you include your sass, make sure its last. As a last resort, you may use !important.

Comment: First, right-click, "inspect element", and take a look at the parsed CSS rules. Chances are a more specific rule is overriding it. If that doesn't do the trick, show us your CSS rule.

Comment: I cant find parsed CSS in the inspect element.

Comment: Well for a start you have no `:hover` in the SASS you've provided.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about specificity, also as mentioned in the comments your SASS files need to be loaded after the bootstrap files so they are parsed last. They're called cascading stylesheets for a reason :)

[Read up on specificity here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), it's a fundamental CSS concept

Try adding a unique class/id to one of your parent elements (if needbe) but just this should be specific enough:

```
.sidebar .nav #activeRow:hover
```

if not then add that unique id/class

```
#awesome.sidebar .nav #activeRow:hover
```

If nothing works, you're in a rush etc. use:

```
background-color: green !important
```

This isn't great practice though, you can end up digging yourself a hole. It's better to work out what's got greatest specificity and write more specific code.

Better yet if you're comfortable with SASS, [download the bootstrap libraries SASS files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/stylesheets) and update the bootstrap core, this is quite an advanced option though.

I assume you're also using `:hover`?

If you're just styling `nav li{ color: white}` and then `#activeRow { color: green}` that wont work. You need to use `#activeRow:hover`

To be view parsed CSS in your inspector, right click the page, click inspect, make sure you're on the 'Elements' tab then you'll see this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SASS rule has to be:

```
#activeRow>a:focus,#activeRow>a:hover
   background-color: green
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOxZaE